# SWT: how to create a plain push button from an action

Tags: java, swt, action, jface

I need a `Button` build from an `IAction`. Should I do that myself or is there already something in JFace which I can reuse? Note, I need the button instance, because I want to make it the default button in a dialog.

With `new ActionContributionItem(action).fill(parent);` I don't seem to be able to get the button instance.

Comment: Thanks for mentioning this `ActionContributionItem.fill` method, this really helped for my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After `fill(parent)` I think you can call parent.getChildren().  I expect the new button will be the last entry in the returned Control[].  Therefore:

```
Control kids[] = parent.getChildren();

if (kids != null && kids.length != 0) {
  getShell().setDefaultButton( (Button)kids[kids.length - 1] );

}
```

If it's not stuck on the end, you'll have to get the list list of children before and after, and find the new entry... but it'll almost certainly be tacked on the end.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I'm doing now. A small hack, but helps at the moment.

Answer (score 3):

I think that it's better way to use `getWidget()` method from `ActionContributionItem` to get `Button` instance associated with `ActionContributionItem`.

```
    ActionContributionItem aci = new ActionContributionItem(action);
    ai.fill(parent);
    Button widget = (Button) ai.getWidget();
```

Comment: +1 Much better, yes.  Casting to a button is quite benign compared to "grab the last kid and hope its our button AND cast it to a button".

Comment: Yeah but API is in this case pretty strange, cos if you don't use `fill` method and use `ToolBarManager/MenuManager/CoolBarManager` with `add` method you get `ToolItem/MenuItem` instead of `Button` with `getWidget` method. It would be nice to have actions API more complex and don't need to grab underlying widgets.